# KV filter logstash value_split

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack

Hi i am using kv filter to split my string I wanted to know how do I put the values after I split em. For example:

My logs look like below:

```
47.30.221.46 - - [04/Sep/2017:13:24:44 +0530] "GET /api/v1.2/places/search/json?username=gaurav.saxena889&location=28.5506382,77.2689024&query=sunrise%20hy&explain=true&bridge=true HTTP/1.1" 200 2522 45402
47.30.221.46 - - [04/Sep/2017:13:24:46 +0530] "GET /api/v1.2/places/search/json?username=gaurav.saxena889&location=28.5506382,77.2689024&query=hy&explain=true&bridge=true HTTP/1.1" 200 2169 55267
47.30.221.46 - - [04/Sep/2017:13:24:47 +0530] "GET /api/v1.2/places/search/json?username=gaurav.saxena889&location=28.5506382,77.2689024&query=hyun&explain=true&bridge=true HTTP/1.1" 200 2530 29635
47.30.221.46 - - [04/Sep/2017:13:24:47 +0530] "GET /api/v1.2/places/search/json?username=gaurav.saxena889&location=28.5506382,77.2689024&query=hyunda&explain=true&bridge=true HTTP/1.1" 200 2572 25449
47.30.221.46 - - [04/Sep/2017:13:24:48 +0530] "GET /api/v1.2/places/search/json?username=gaurav.saxena889&location=28.5506382,77.2689024&query=hyundai&explain=true&bridge=true HTTP/1.1" 200 3576 28007
47.30.221.46 - - [04/Sep/2017:13:24:58 +0530] "GET /api/v1.2/places/search/json?username=gaurav.saxena889&location=28.5506382,77.2689024&query=su&explain=true&bridge=true HTTP/1.1" 200 2354 96861
47.30.221.46 - - [04/Sep/2017:13:24:58 +0530] "GET /api/v1.2/places/search/json?username=gaurav.saxena889&location=28.5506382,77.2689024&query=sun&explain=true&bridge=true HTTP/1.1" 200 3224 50897
```

My logstash config file looks like below:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
    client_inactivity_timeout => 86400
  }
}

filter {
    grok {
        match => {
            "message" => "%{IPORHOST:client_ip} %{HTTPDUSER:ident} %{HTTPDUSER:auth} \[%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}\] \"(?:%{WORD:method} /api/v%{NUMBER:version}/%{DATA:resource}/%{DATA:subresource}/%{DATA:response_type}\?%{NOTSPACE:request}(?: HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion})?|%{DATA:rawrequest})\" %{NUMBER:response_code} (?:%{NUMBER:data_transfered}|-) %{NUMBER:response_time}"
        }
    }
    kv {
        source => "request"
        field_split => "&"
    }

    if [query] {
        mutate {
            rename => { "query" => "searched_keword" }
        }
    } else if [keyword] {
        mutate {
            rename => { "keyword" => "searched_keyword" }
        }
    }

    if [refLocation] {
        mutate {
            rename => { "refLocation" => "location" }
        }
    }

    mutate {
        convert => { "response_code" => "integer" }
    }

    mutate {
        convert => { "data_transfered" => "integer" }
    }

    mutate {
        convert => { "version" => "float" }
    }

    mutate {
        convert => { "response_time" => "integer" }
    }

    if [location] {
        kv {
           source => "location"
           value_split => ","
        }
    }


}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
    index => "logstash_apachelogs"
    document_type => "log"
  }
}
```

If you have a look at the last `kv` filter, I've split my location value with a `,`. I have 2 questions:

1. If you see from the logs I have a `location=28.5506382,77.2689024` using the kv filter I split the values using the `,` now how do I use the splited values in a goip filter which takes the vaues as below:

   geoip {
   source => "ClientIP"
   target => "geoip"
   add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][longitude]}" ]
   add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][latitude]}" ]
   }
2. How do i replace the %20 in the query parameter with a white space?

Comment: Why do you want to use the geoip filter if you already have a location? The geoip filter gives a location to an ip. Also your last kv filter won't work, since there are no field name in the location field (its value is something like 28.5506382,77.2689024).

Comment: 2. filter mutate, option gsub. It's easy enough that you should not need any help setting that up. Or you could search older questions on that subject.